# Progressively measurable process.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $b: [0,T] \times \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the properties:

1. For all $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ the process $(t,\omega) \mapsto b(t,\omega, x)$ is progressively measurable.
2. There exits $ C > 0 $ such that for all $\omega, t, x_1, x_2 $ we have
   $$ | b(t,\omega, x_1) - b(t,\omega, x_2) |  \leq C | x_1 - x_2 |. $$

Let $X = (X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ be progressively measurable. I want to show that the process 
$$ (t, \omega) \mapsto b(t,\omega, X_t(\omega) ) $$
is progressively measurable. This should follow from 1. and 2. but I was not able to prove it. I hope someone can help me out.

**Edit:** I actually need a more general result. Let $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite second moment. Equip this space with the Wasserstein metric $W^2.$ Then, $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Polish space.

Let $b: [0,T] \times \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the properties:

1. For all $ x \in \mathbb{R}, \mu \in \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ the process $(t,\omega) \mapsto b(t,\omega, x, \mu)$ is progressively measurable.
2. There exits $ C > 0 $ such that for all $\omega, t, x_1, x_2 , \mu_1, \mu_2$ we have
   $$ | b(t,\omega, x_1, \mu_1) - b(t,\omega, x_2, \mu_2) |  \leq C \big( | x_1 - x_2 | + W^2(\mu_1, \mu_2) \big). $$

Let $X = (X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ be progressively measurable. Let $P(X_t)$ be the push forward measure of $X_t$. I want to show that the process 
$$ (t, \omega) \mapsto b(t,\omega, X_t(\omega), P(X_t) ) $$
is progressively measurable.

I tried to imitate the proof of the easier case. However, the problem seems to be that I cannot split $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ into disjoint sets of "small radius". Do you have an idea how to deal with this?

Comment: may I know whether $t\to P(X_t)$ is Borel measurable under the above condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $b_n(t,\omega,x):=b(t,\omega,k/n)$ for $x\in[k/n,(k+1)/n)$ and integer $k$, where $n=1,2,\ldots$. The corresponding process 
$$
X^{(n)}_t(\omega):=b_n(t,\omega,X_t(\omega))=\sum_k b(t,\omega,k/n)1_{[k/n,(k+1)/n)}(X_t(\omega))
$$
is a countable sum of progressive process, and so is progressive. And because of the uniform Lipschitz condition you have imposed, you have the uniform convergence:
$$
\lim_n\sup_{0\le t\le T}|X^{(n)}_t(\omega)-X_t(\omega)|=0.
$$
It follows that $X$ is progressive as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. I have one remark: I think uniform convergence is not necessary. Pointwise limits of measurable functions are measurable.  Therefore, condition 2. can be relaxed to have the $C$ depending on $(t, \omega).$ Is this correct?

Comment: No doubt a weaker condition  would suffice but th uniformity makes the pointwise convergence easy to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I posted a more general version. Maybe you could also help me out with this one.

Comment: For the more general version, I was missing this piece of information: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875058/cover-of-a-metric-space. Using this fact we can use the same proof.